# boost coroutine with multi core

Tags: c++, multicore, boost-coroutine

My tcp server is based on this [boost coroutine server example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/spawn/echo_server.cpp).

There're lots of request per second, the server have two cores but only one is used, it never goes over than 50% cpu in task manager's performance tab, and one core is always free:
[image]

How to make boost::coroutine work with multiple cores?

I just came up a solution that add a [thread_pool](https://github.com/progschj/ThreadPool/blob/master/ThreadPool.h):

```
#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/spawn.hpp>
#include "thread_pool.h"
#include <iostream>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

class session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<session>
{
public:
  explicit session(tcp::socket socket) { }

  void go()
  {
      std::cout << "dead loop" << std::endl;
      while(1) {} // causes 100% cpu usage, just for test
  }
};

int main()
{
  try
  {

    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    thread_pool pool(1000); // maximum 1000 threads

    boost::asio::spawn(io_service,
        [&](boost::asio::yield_context yield)
        {
          tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service,
            tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 80));

          for (;;)
          {
            boost::system::error_code ec;
            tcp::socket socket(io_service);
            acceptor.async_accept(socket, yield[ec]);
            if (!ec) {
                pool.enqueue([&] { // add this to pool
                    std::make_shared<session>(std::move(socket))->go();
                });
            }
          }
        });

    io_service.run();
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {}

  return 0;
}
```

Now the code seems running with 100% cpu after *telnet 127.0.0.1 80* twice.

But what's the common way of using coroutine with multi cores?

Comment: Can you post an image of your task manager ? are you sure it is using only one core?

Comment: @ali786, post updated with image. Coroutine is single-threaded, so I guess one thread cannot run on multiple cores.

Comment: Yes, the very idea of coroutines is that only one system thread is able to run several functions _concurrently_. If you want to run your functions _simultaneously_ (to occupy both cores) you'll need at least 2 system threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thread only runs on one core, so you have to create multiple threads with separate coroutines. asio already contains some thread management support, so you mostly have to start some threads:

```
int main() {
  std::vector<std::thread> pool;
  try {
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    {
      for(auto threadCount = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
          threadCount;--threadCount)
        pool.emplace_back([](auto io_s) {return io_s->run(); }, &io_service);
    }

    // Normal code
  } catch(std::exception &e) {}
  for(auto &thread : pool) 
    thread.join();
  return 0;
}
```

The important thing is to run `io_service.run()` on every thread. Then, after `.async_accept`, you can call

```
io_service.post(&session::go, std::make_shared<session>(std::move(socket)))
```

to run the session somewhere in the pool.